# Adding JButtons to a Panel that Have the Same Name Yet They Are Different. Why? (Java) (Swing)

Tags: java, swing, object

I am working on a dummy project that adds x amount of buttons depending on how many buttons are contained in an `ArrayList`.

The following code creates a `new` button each time the `for` loop block executes and adds it to the `ArrayList` named `listOfButtons`.

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        JButton button = new JButton("Record " + String.valueOf(i + 1));
        button.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        listOfButtons.add(button);

    }
```

Then I simply add the buttons contained in `listOfButtons` to the panel.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        panel.add(listOfButtons.get(i));
    }
```

With this context; my question is why and how is it legal to create unique button objects with the same name: `button`. I always understood object creation as this: when a programmer creates a new Object reference variable that has the same name as another reference variable, then the new reference variable will point to a different single object in memory.

Comment: When you create a new button inside your loop, then that button is 'locally' defined. That means that in each iteration the old variable called 'button' is unknown (except that a reference to it exists in your list.). The result is that each entry in your list has a unique reference, but the entries themselves do not have a name.
I hope that came accross ok !!

Comment: Thank you all for the great answers. I am upvoting all, but they are not visible due to my reputation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scope of the reference `button` is the for body. On each iteration, the reference is a new one, hence the part `JButton button`. You are also creating new objects, hence `new JButton(...)`. You also let the new reference point to the newly created object on the same line, hence the `=` (assignment operator).

We are talking only about duplicate reference declarations, not about assignments nor object creations.

This is illegal:

```
JButton button;
JButton button;
```

As well as this:

```
{
    JButton button;
    {
        JButton button;
    }
}
```

This is legal:

```
{
    JButton button;
}

{
    JButton button;
}
```

That's because the references are declared in disjoint scopes.

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with object scope. Once each for loop iteration has completed, the scope has now changed, thus the new Button with the name `button` is of a different scope.

Much the same as how you can have 2 methods with the same variable names.

```
public void method1() {
    int value = 0;
}

public void method2() {
    int value = 1;
}
```

Both of these variables are allowed also, due to different scope.

At the end of each of the for loop iterations, the `button` variable reference is thrown away. The list may still be looking at it, but it cannot be referenced by the name `button`

Answer (score 0):

The `button` has a reference to the newly created `JButton`. If you change the reference on button by assigning it a new reference by creating another `JButton` it does not mean that the previous one will be deleted.

You could also do this and it has the same effect

```
listOfButtons.add(new JButton("new Button created without assigning it somewhere"));
```